# EF Core - what about database initializers?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

In EF 6 we used database initializers for the following reasons:

- Seeding data
- Using seeding to define indices
- Using seeding to define the database collation
- Using seeindg to set "sparse"
- Deciding on the action if the database model does not match (e.g., drop-and-recreate or create-if-not-exists)

Seeding and indices can now be defined in OnModelCreating, however, I still need a hook to execute  raw SQL commands to define the database collation and set "sparse" - how to do that in EF Core?

What decides in EF Core which "initialization strategy" (e.g., drop-and-recreate) is performed when connection to the database? There does not seem to be a replacement for this at all?

Comment: Yep, there is no equivalent of database initializers. EF Core has no "initialization strategy" concept at all. All db schema modifications must be handled with migrations. There is `migrationBuilder.Sql` command for raw SQL/DDL.

Comment: So whether the database is dropped and recreated or created if not exists or nothing at all is controlled via migrations now too? Or is this something I must do on my own? We didn't even use EF 6 migrations...

Comment: There are some methods `EnsureDeleted`, `EnsureCreated`, `Migrate`, but you are supposed to call them explicitly. There is no equivalent of update if model changes - probably because there are no "automatic migrations" as in EF6. All EFC migrations must be pre created using their tools.  For more info, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/